# Ícone do SOpt não aparece no data.stackexchange

Tags: bug, status-pronto, data-explorer

Notei que em vários lugares do http://data.stackexchange.com/ o ícone do SOpt não é encontrado e a imagem fica quebrada:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O endereço da imagem (inexistente) é http://data.stackexchange.com/content/br/img/favicon.ico

Um link que funciona e parece ser do padrão utilizado pelos outros no `data` é http://cdn.sstatic.net/br/img/favicon.ico

Fiquei em dúvida se aqui seria o lugar correto pra postar, já que não é um problema diretamente do SOpt, mas o Data Explorer também não tem meta.

Comment: Eu nem consigo pesquisar sequer, mas ninguém quer saber...

Comment: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2617/problema-com-sele%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-parent-user

Comment: @JorgeB. entra no site http://data.stackexchange.com/, clica na seta para baixo, e procura a comunidade do SOPT.

Comment: Nada @Math vê a minha pergunta vou editar...

Comment: O link da imagem também está quebrado no meu feed. Não parei para analisar qual o endereço que ele tenta buscar. Mudou acho que na graduação ou pouco tempo antes.

Comment: Reporting here is fine, and I'll get this fixed. Thank you! :)

Comment: @Tim - I fixed it.

Comment: @Oded can um check my problem http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2617/problema-com-sele%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-parent-user?

Comment: @Oded Awesome, thanks!